# What does "invalid account discriminator" mean in Anchor?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I'm trying to fetch an account from a public key:

```js
await program.account.myAccountType.fetch(somePubkey);
```

But then Anchor throws an error saying:

```
Invalid account discriminator
```

What is an account discriminator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An account discriminator is few bytes that Anchor puts at the front of an account, like a header. It lets anchor know what type of account it should deserialize the data as.

This error happens if you try to to fetch something as `myAccountType`, but it's actually a pubkey for some other account, like a Token Account, or another account within your program.

Here's some things you could try:

- console logging `somePubkey` and putting it into [the explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/)
- making extra double sure that you meant `program.account.myAccountType` and not `program.account.someOtherAccountType`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this problem occurred after I did `anchor idl init [OPTIONS] --filepath <FILEPATH> <PROGRAM_ID>`.

Once I ran this command the frontend started to throw `Error: Invalid account discriminator` every time I tried to run `await connection.getProgramAccounts()`.

I wanted to do the `anchor idl init` because I wanted to fetch the idl using `Program.fetchIdl()` instead of passing `idl` as a json object, which requires me to copy it from `target/idl/<program-name>.json` into my React frontend and then import the json into my project...

To fix the issue I had to rebuild and redeploy anchor program by running `anchor build` and then `anchor deploy`. Once I did this then I had to pass the `idl` as a json object into the `Program.getProgramAccounts()` function.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error come up when I had put my accounts in the wrong order. As a result the discriminator didn't match up with what it expected.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I am using a Non-camelcase type for account struct.

**Previous**

[image]

**After Fix**
[image]